# Why my emulator/device and design screen in AS show different layout ? I am concerned about the thing below 'BILL TOTAL'

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

[Please click here to view the screenshot.Please tell me the reason. I can send you the codes if u require.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4jIw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4jIw.png)

Comment: They seem to be showing the same layout. Please explain **in detail** what differences you see that concern you.

Comment: Since it is your first question on SO, you might read [the guide on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question afterwards.

Comment: Hey CommonsWare i have edited the picture and circled the desired area. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The design preview will not show any live running code or logic that the device or emulator will. You can override this by adding one of the [tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html) references to the layout, but otherwise it will just use the default data set inside the XML layout attributes.

Comment: My problem is just that why my emulator is not updating the code applied to it, although it can easily be seen on design window.

Comment: If you share your XML and activity code, I can give you a more thorough answer, but my answer still stands. The design pane cannot execute code, so it is a static representation of the layout with no logic in place.

Comment: <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBillTotalAmount2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvBillTotal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_big"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/main.msg.billtotalresult"

        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: resources>
    <string name="app_name">Tip Calculator</string>
    <string name="main.msg.billamount">Bill Amount</string>
    <string name="main.hint.billamount">Enter Bill Amount Here</string>
    <string name="main.msg.servicerating">Service Rating</string>
    <string name="main.msg.tippercent">%s%%Tip Percent</string>
    <string name="main.msg.tiptotal">$%sTip Total</string>
    <string name="main.msg.billtotal">Bill Total</string>
    <string name="main.msg.billtotalresult">%s</string>
</resources>